# Does range have to calculate all previous values when using a index

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python 3, range supports indexing but I am wondering exactly how that works.

For example: `range(100000000000000000000000000)[-1]`

I have a basic understanding that the range function actually returns a range object that takes up a limited amount of memory. Does that mean that to get to the last value, it has to calculate all the previous values?

Comment: That's not really slicing notation. Slicing uses colons like ':'. That's just a special form of indexing/subscripting.

Comment: Oh you are right! Such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not required to get previous value to get the last value.

It is computed by [`compute_item` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d8e352e2f110/Objects/rangeobject.c#l236) (which is called by [`compute_range_item`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d8e352e2f110/Objects/rangeobject.c#l251) <- [`range_item`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d8e352e2f110/Objects/rangeobject.c#l310) ...).

*From Python 3.3 source code (Objects/rangeobjects.c)*

```
static PyObject *
compute_item(rangeobject *r, PyObject *i)
{
    PyObject *incr, *result;
    /* PyLong equivalent to:
     *    return r->start + (i * r->step)
     */
    incr = PyNumber_Multiply(i, r->step);
    if (!incr)
        return NULL;
    result = PyNumber_Add(r->start, incr);
    Py_DECREF(incr);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hm.. Any idea why `timeit.timeit('range(9999999999999)[-1]')` takes almost 30% longer than `timeit.timeit('range(9999999999999)[1]')`?

Comment: @aIKid, Negative index should be converted to positive index. I didn't profiled it (I can't right now). That could be one reason. [**See this line from the source code**](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d8e352e2f110/Objects/rangeobject.c#l260).

Comment: @aIKid, There's another possible reason. `range(9999999999999)[-1]` returns `9999999999998`, while `range(9999999999999)[1]` returns `1`. `1` takes 28 bytes (and interned in CPython), `9999999999998` takes 32 bytes. (CPython 3.3.2 64bit). Allocating/deallocating object multiple times can take a time.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not:

```
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit('range(10)[-1]'))
>>> 0.5438045680057257

print(timeit.timeit('range(100000000000000000000000000)[-1]'))
>>> 0.7502937959798146
```