# Does slicing a range use additional space as with slicing a list?

Tags: python, memory, range, slice, space

If I slice a range like below in Python terminal, I'm returned with another representation of the same range. As with lists, does slicing a range allocate additional space?

```
>>> range(1,5)[::-1]
range(4, 0, -1)
```

In other words, does this create a new range?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494933/does-range-have-to-calculate-all-previous-values-when-using-a-index help?

Answer (score 1):

> The advantage of the range type over a regular list or tuple is that a range object will always take the same (small) amount of memory, no matter the size of the range it represents (as it only stores the start, stop and step values, calculating individual items and subranges as needed).

- reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range

```
import sys

print(sys.getsizeof(range(1,5)))

print(sys.getsizeof(range(1,5)[::-1]))

print(sys.getsizeof(list(range(1,5))))

print(sys.getsizeof(list(range(1,5)[::-1])))

print(sys.getsizeof(list(range(1,5))[::-1]))

print(sys.getsizeof([1,2,3,4][::-1]))
```

```
48
48
120
120
96
96
```

No copy is made from the first range (so, space complexity is the same if applied once for both `range(1,5)` and `range(1,5)[::-1]`) but you'll get a new range object.

```
range1 = range(1,5)
range2 = range1
range3 = range1[::-1]

print(id(range1))
print(id(range2))
print(id(range3))
```

```
140671877466800
140671877466800
140671877466608
```